# iPython Notebook: render cell as HTML from variable content

Tags: jupyter-notebook

In iPython Notebook I have a cell where I define a variable (say `html`) and assign to it an html content (response content of a http get request). I would like to render this variable into another cell as html. Is it possible? How can I do it?

eg:

```
[1] html = '''<html><h1>a heading</h1><ul><li>one</li><li>two</li><li>three</li></ul></html>'''
```

I would like to render this in the next cell.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve the desired goal by:

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
display(HTML(response.content))
```

I found the solution [here](http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/Printing-HTML-within-IPython-Notebook-IPython-specific-prettyprint-tt5016624.html#a5016631).

More info can be found [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/1.x/examples/notebooks/Part%205%20-%20Rich%20Display%20System.ipynb).